# Mixed model, not including time of measurement - can this be done?

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, random-effects-model

I have measured a reaction time and heart rate from subjects twice. The data includes two groups. In order to make my data bigger, I am combining these two measures. Therefore, each subject is having two values. I am not interested if there is change over time, but if the heart rate explains the variability in the reaction time and if there is a significant heart rate * group interaction. My model would be written like this:

```
lmer(reaction_time ~ heart_rate*group + (1|id), data = data)
```

Can I perform this kind of modelling? I mean, is it ok to leave time point 1 and 2 out of my model? I am not interested in if they learn to answer faster either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I perform this kind of modelling? I mean, is it ok to leave time point 1 and 2 out of my model? I am not interested in if they learn to answer faster either.

Yes, there is no problem with this. You are effectively modelling the mean reaction time.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!